# Defining data-specific Clojure functions, possibly with macro?

Tags: macros, clojure, etl

I am dealing with processing a lot of data, and the type of processing depends on the data being processed.  The ultimate goal is to have a function for each element of each row that executes efficiently.  Below is simply an example using division by averages, but I am trying to get to a solution that could apply any function.

Say I want to read in a vector of vectors of numbers and return the result of dividing the first number by the average number in its position and the result of subtracting the minimum number from the second number.

Example:

Inputs:

```
(def inputs
[[1.0,1.0]
 [2.0,4.0]
 [3.0,9.0]])
```

Averages:

```
(def avgs
[2.0,7.0])
```

Mininums:

```
(def mins
[1.0,1.0])
```

Outputs:

```
(def outputs
[[0.50,0.00]
 [1.00,3.00]
 [1.50,8.00]])
```

Directives:

(def avg-ids [0])
   (def subtr-ids [1])

A naive approach is to look up the divisor for each position:

```
(defn avg-elem [element position]
  (/ element (nth avgs position)))

(defn subtr-elem [element position]
  (- element (nth mins position)))

(mapv
    #(map-indexed
      (fn [elem idx] (if (is-avg-idx? idx) (avg-elem elem idx) (subtr-elem elem idx)))
    %)
inputs)
```

What I would like to do is the following:

```
(fn [elem] (/ elem 2.0))
(fn [elem] (- elem 1.0))
```

and have some sort of function applying the corresponding function to each element in each row.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you mean by "a solution that could apply any function". What do you need that isn't provided by Clojure's sequence processing primitives? Can you give a better example? Honestly, it sounds to me like you're over-designing without having a clear idea of what your requirements are.

Comment: Essentially, I am looking to process a vector of vectors (matrix), like shown. When I receive the matrix, I receive a list of directives for each column. Each directive corresponds to a function. The application must have the flexibility to include new directives and functions easily in the future. Right now, I use something similar to the naive approach, and it has major inefficiency.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but here are some ways to divide each column of `inputs` matrix to the corresponding element of the `avgs` vector:

```
(mapv (partial mapv /) inputs (repeat avgs))
```

or

```
(mapv #(mapv / % avgs) inputs)
```

Comment: My goal is to define a function for each column. While your solution accomplishes the exact scenario I have laid out, it does not generalize to other functions I might want to perform on the column. I'll update the description.

Comment: @user1559027 to generalize to other functions, replace `/` with some other function.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after?

```
(def row-fns (map (fn [avg] #(/ % avg)) avgs))
(mapv (fn [row] (mapv #(%1 %2) row-fns row)) inputs)
```

Replace `row-fns` with any list of single-argument functions.

Comment: Would taking this approach prevent looking up the required element from avgs each time an element is being processed? Could `row-fns` contains functions of different types? It looks like that's the case.